# How to inject interface to Account controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

In a default MVC project, I'm trying to inject a new interface to `AccountController`.

```
private readonly INotificationService _notificationService;

private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

public AccountController(){}

public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, 
    ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, INotificationService notificationService)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
    SignInManager = signInManager;
    _notificationService = notificationService;
}
```

But, my `_notificationService` is always null, I think because they are using the empty constructor.

I'm using Unity.MVC5 to register my component, like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IMessageSender, AuthMessageSender>();
container.RegisterType<INotificationService, NotificationService>();
container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
container.RegisterType<ManageController>(new InjectionConstructor());
```

How can I inject my interface to `AccountController`?

Comment: Have you tried removing the default constructor to see if that is the cause?

Comment: If I remove the default constructor I got an error.

Comment: And what is the error. if it is complaining about no default constructor then that probably means that you have not configured the DependencyResolver. or one of the dependencies has an exception when initialized.  Show how dependency injection was setup.

Comment: container.RegisterType<IMessageSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        container.RegisterType<INotificationService, NotificationService>();
        container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
        container.RegisterType<ManageController>(new InjectionConstructor());

Comment: That is only part. provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem. Otherwise there is not much help we can provided with an incomplete picture of what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

No need to inject Controller by `new InjectionConstructor()` instead you can resolve it by something like this :

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
container.RegisterType<AccountController>(
           new InjectionConstructor(
             container.Resolve<ApplicationUserManager>(), 
             container.Resolve<ApplicationSignInManager>(),
             container.Resolve<INotificationService>()));
```

[Microsoft Docs: 3 - Dependency Injection with Unity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/dn178463(v%3Dpandp.30))